Change window title in DOSBOX
I'm working in an ASM file in VS Code and I'm using some extensions that let me run it. I want to change the title when the window pops out.
The window name is DOSBOX 0,74-3, Cpu speed: .... instead of something similar to for instance, "project"

Suggested google keywords: dosbox window title. I see a fairly useful answer around the top so it should be a good exercise for your research skills. (spoiler: not possible with official builds of dosbox)

Open DOSBox.exe in HxD. Search for DOSBox %s, Cpu speed: %8d cycles, Frameskip %2d, Program: %8s and write in this place whatever You want. Should work if this is what You are looking for. ;)

@Nassau, it worked, thanks!
